# Breeze/Knockout dropdown value is not updated in database if caption is selected instead of value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js, breeze, durandal

I am using Breezejs with Durandal in my .net application.

When i try to edit a section which contains

1) Text box

2) Dropdownlist with caption and options

3) TextArea

4) Button

Onclick of edit button, i am binding these controls with their respective values(till then it works fine).

After i change textbox value to "test123" and dropdown values to it's "caption" and clicking on save button. In save function I am creating Breeze entity in modified state and updating them as shown below,

```
var personEntity = breeze.manager.createEntity('TableName', { Id: id }, breeze.EntityState.Unchanged);
personEntity.entityAspect.entityState.setModified();
personEntity.name(name); //"test123"
personEntity.dropdownValue(status) //I have selected the caption, means value is undefined
personEntity.textArea(address); //No change
```

then making savechanges() to DB.

In table text box value is updated properly but the value of dropdownlist is not updated(from some value 
to Null);

Kindly suggest me some solution so that i can save null value in DB if caption is selected.

Thanks in Advance......

Comment: Try using `''` instead of `null`.

Comment: you shpuld show the some more code and HTML to understand when you call save changes, how you bind the properties, and so on.

Comment: If you inspect the payload that is sent to the server upon saveChanges (e.g. using the Network tab of your browser's F12 dev tools), do you see the dropdownValue being sent?

Comment: @Steve.... 

I checked in network tab the dropdown value is Null. But still Db is not updating by Null value.

Comment: @JotaBe......
<input type="text" data-bind="value: lastName/>
<select data-bind="options: statusArray, optionsText: 'Choices', optionsValue: 'Choices', value: status, optionsCaption: 'Select an item...'"></select>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: saveData">Save</button>
-------------------
function TaskListViewModel() {
var self = this;   self.status= ko.observable();  self.lastName = ko.observable();   self.statusArray = ko.observableArray([
{Choices: "Alignment Complete"}, {Choices: 'PQR'} ]);
self.saveData = function (){  
//Creating & updating Entity
saveChanges('Message');

Comment: @Pankajya. Please, edit the question and include your code in it, not in a comment, where it's not visible and hardly readable. Thank you.

Comment: my guess is db field is a not null field

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `ContextProvider` on the server is not detecting that the `dropdownValue` has changed.  It determines the changed properties by looking at the `entityAspect.originalValues`.  Since you create a new entity with dropdownValue = undefined, and you set it to undefined, no change is detected.

Change your code to initialize the dropdownValue to something else:

```
var personEntity = breeze.manager.createEntity('TableName', 
    { Id: id, dropdownValue: 'something' });
personEntity.name(name);
personEntity.dropdownValue(status);
personEntity.textArea(address);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply......But in my Entity there are total 10-15 dropdowns. Is it good practice to pass all those values during Entity creation? Can you please suggest some other solution for it???